# Closing or Hiding forms causes a cross thread error

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am baffled by this simple task i do over and over again.

I have an array of child forms.  The array is initiated in another form's constructor:

```
frmChildren = new ChildGUI[20];
```

When the user requests to see a child form, i do this:

```
if (frmChildren[nb] == null)
{
    frmChildren[nb] = new ChildGUI();
    frmChildren[nb].MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
}
frmChildren[nb].Show();
```

So far this **works**.  In the background i can download new content for these forms.  When a download is finished i fire a ChildChange event.  Here is where it stops working.
I simply want to close/hide any forms open then regenerate a new set of -frmChildren = new ChildGUI[20];- here is one of many trials:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < frmChildren.Length;i++ )
        {
            if (frmChildren[i] != null)
            {
                //frmChildren[i].BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(delegate
                //{
                    frmChildren[i].Close();
                //}));
            }
        }             
        frmChildren= new ChildGUI[20];
```

I get a Cross Thread exception on the .Close(). Notice i've already tried doing an invoke, but doing so bypasses the !=null for some reason.  I think it may have something to do with the garbage collector.  Anybody have an input?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that your anonymous method is capturing `i` - so by the time it's *actually* invoked in the UI thread, you've got a different value of `i`, which may be null. Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < frmChildren.Length; i++)
{
    ChildGUI control = frmChildren[i];
    if (control != null)
    {
        control.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(delegate
        {
            control.Close();
        }));
    }
}             
frmChildren = new ChildGUI[20];
```

See [Eric Lippert's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) for why introducing a new variable *within* the loop fixes the problem.

EDIT: If you want to use a `foreach` loop, it would look like this:

```
foreach (ChildGUI control in frmChildren)
{
    // Create a "new" variable to be captured
    ChildGUI copy = control;
    if (copy != null)
    {
        copy.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(delegate
        {
            copy.Close();
        }));
    }
}             
frmChildren = new ChildGUI[20];
```

Just as an aside, you can use the fact that you just want to call a void method to make the code slightly simpler. As this no longer uses an anonymous method, you can make do away with the "inner" variable:

```
foreach (ChildGUI control in frmChildren)
{
    if (control != null)
    {
        control.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(control.Close));
    }
}             
frmChildren = new ChildGUI[20];
```

Comment: I've tried the same code stated above with a foreach.  How would a foreach be different?
ODDLY your solution works! +1

Comment: Thanks for the link explaining why this works the way it does. If you didn't care about closing the forms asynchronously, I think you could replace BeginInvoke with Invoke instead of introducing another variable. Since Invoke is synchronous, the value of the iteration variable `i` will not have changed yet.

Comment: @Lily: With a foreach loop, you'd still need to introduce an extra variable *inside the loop*. That's the important bit.